# How do I disallow weak cipher suites on our auth0-hosted login page?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127817/what-cipher-suites-are-no-longer-support-under-amazon-cloudfronts-tlsv1-2-2021).  Instead of our website ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com) which uses [Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html#secure-connections-supported-ciphers)) , this question relates to a login page we have that is hosted on [auth0.com](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/custom-domains/self-managed-certificates/tls-ssl) (login-stg.example.com).  We know this because if you ping our login page, it comes back with the following domain:

ping login-stg.example.com
PING example-stg-cd-aeoaqmqpnciknwc2.edge.tenants.auth0.com : 56 data bytes

This auth0-hosted login page uses the following weak cipher suites that need to be disallowed / removed:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

In order to remove this weak cipher suites from our auth0-hosted login page, do I need to [contact auth0.com](https://auth0.com/docs/troubleshoot/customer-support/open-and-manage-support-tickets) ? Or is this something I can do by logging into my [auth0.com dashboard](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/auth0-overview/dashboard)?

The closest relevant docs I found on auth0's page is [this one](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-can-i-disable-tls-1-0-tls-1-1-and-weak-ciphers-with-custom-domains/45078) and [this one](https://community.auth0.com/t/why-are-weak-ciphers-used-on-our-login-page/111831). On that page they are recommending to run a `cURL PATCH` command to upgrade to a new/modern cipher suite.   In the other doc, they are recommending [configuring custom domains](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/custom-domains/self-managed-certificates?_gl=1*o537ea*_gcl_au*ODgzNzI5NTkzLjE2OTMzMjIzNTI.#provide-your-domain-name-to-auth0).

Comment: The [help/on-topic] can provide guidance on what questions are on-topic here. This one appears off-topic to me.